# Extracting rows based on a cell value on dynamic data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to extract rows from an Excel sheet based on the cell value. Consider below example:

**Sheet 1 columns:**

```
Group | Question | Option1 | Option2 | Answer
```

**Sheet 2 columns:**

```
Question | Option1 | Option2 | Answer
```

As demonstrated above, I'm filtering the rows from Sheet 1 based on the **Group** and populating the data in a separate Excel sheet.

**Issue:** If data is added in Sheet 1, how can it reflect in Sheet 2 simultaneously.

Comment: Do you mean something like [Dynamically Filter Data from One Worksheet to Another in Microsoft Excel 2010](https://www.exceltip.com/tips/dynamically-filter-data-from-one-worksheet-to-another-in-microsoft-excel-2010.html) or [How to filter data from one worksheet to another dynamically in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4189-excel-dynamic-filter-to-new-sheet.html) Also [Copy Data to Another Worksheet with Advanced Filter](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/) is a different solution. This was just one click after googeling.

Comment: Yes, the functionality is the same but first two solutions are not working. 

Already tried using advanced filter but that does not work when we have to copy to another sheet.

Not sure if the issue is with excel or something else.

Comment: The first two solutions are definitely working. At least the first one that I used myself. And it definitely does exactly what you described in your question. The only other way is writing a VBA macro yourself (no one will do it for you), but I don't see a need to write a macro for this.